# Why are the numbers of an ordered list repeating?

Tags: support

See [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30459/how-to-i-safely-anchor-a-safety-line-to-a-chimney) question.  In the text of the question I have the numbers "1." and "2.", however when viewing the question they both display with "1."

Why is this occurring?

Comment: A related effect of this is that when editing a post, you can number all your list items with '1.' and they'll be renumbered for display -- makes it very easy to add or remove items or re-order the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because they are separated by an image and Markdown thinks that it needs to start a new list.

If you indent the image by a space (like I've just done) then Markdown treats the image as part of the list and gets the numbering correct.